# Web application inside iframe in sharepoint doesn't store session variables

Tags: session, iframe

I am attempting to open an application inside an iframe in sharepoint. I do not wish to share any session variable but the we application needs to be able to keep its own session variables.

The iframe and application work in firefox and not in IE 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is described by Q7

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219133530/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324013
Lists a step by step process to resolve the issue.